# Load modal after click link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've been trying to load a modal content after clicking on link in this case "About Product".
Atm on page is more article and every article got modal.
So modal's alose been load with page and modal's make web page slower because evrey single modal been load.

I want to make javascript when i click "About Product" the model will start to load or just:

```
<iframe width="100%" height="540px" src="'.$row['video_url'].'" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Because this part make page slow

There is rest of code:

```
<div class="item-col col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-3">
    <div class="product-wrapper">
        <div class="list-col4">
            <img src="../images/'.$row['productimage'].'" alt="'.$row['productname'].'">
        </div>
        <div class="list-col8" style="padding-bottom: 15px;">
            <div class="gridview">
                <div class="padding-games">
                    <span class="special-price"><span><center>'.$row['productname'].'</center></span></span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#'.$row['id'].'">About Product</a>
            <a href="product-'.$row['title'].'">More</a>
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<!--   product end -->

<!-- Modal -->
<div id="'.$row['id'].'" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <center><h4 class="modal-title"><img src="../images/'.$row['productimage'].'" alt="'.$row['productname'].'"></h4></center>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <iframe width="100%" height="540px" src="'.$row['video_url'].'" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: So you want to load the `iframe` content of the `model` only when the About Product link is clicked by the user,and also show the `dialog`? Correct ?

Comment: yes, because iframe make web page slower

Answer (score 0):

OK we can bind the `a` click event and use it to load the `iframe src` property, if you don't want to load straight away..

`html` :  We add a data attribute `data-link` and add iframe link here to use later. We also add `class` to identify but you can use `id` if you prefer.

```
<a class="about_product" data-toggle="modal" data-link="'.$row['video_url'].'"  data-target="#'.$row['id'].'">About Product</a>
```

iframe

```
<iframe id="myFrame" width="100%" height="540px" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

`script`: Here we attach `click` event to the link with class `.about_product`. onclick `data-src` reference is used and set to the iframe

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".about_product").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#myFrame").attr('src', this.dataset.link);       
    })
});
```

This however is not tested in conjunction with bootstrap js files, so let us know how it goes.

Update: I created a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vs8a7bma/5/) to show how this works.

Comment: Thanks for help but it's don't wrok. iframe is blank on inspect and modal alose

Comment: @vatra Were there any errors in the dev console ? So the modal opens and iframe has no content? Can u inspect, using devtools, the iframe and the link and share the screenshot. I just want to see if the properties are getting updated.

Comment: There is ss of inspect:https://postimg.org/image/3uovbaysz/
And there is code:https://postimg.org/image/kpd9rhn43/

Comment: @vatra Hmm it doesn't seem to add the iframe src property when you clicked the link. That inspect element screen you shared, is that after you clicked the link? Please check my update with jsfiddle on why I wanted to confirm. Also please check if there area any errors in the `console` when you either load the page or click on the link.